# Using mkmf with Ruby ext Linking a Static Library with -L and -I and -l

Tags: c, ruby, extconf.rb, mkmf

Given a simple `gcc` command that follows as:

```
gcc quickrb.c -o main -L /usr/local/lib/quickjs -I /usr/local/lib/quickjs -l quickjs
```

I'm attempting to wrap this inside of a ruby gem extension `extconf.rb` using `mkmf`. Currently I've got:

```
require 'mkmf'

dir_config('quickjs', '/usr/local/lib/quickjs', '/usr/local/include/quickjs')

abort('missing "quickjs.h"') unless find_header('quickjs/quickjs.h')
abort('missing JS_NewRuntime') unless find_library('quickjs', 'JS_NewRuntime', 'quickjs/quickjs.h')
abort('missing JS_NewContext') unless find_library('quickjs', 'JS_NewContext', 'quickjs/quickjs.h')

create_makefile('quickrb/quickrb')
```

This fails with:

```
checking for quickjs/quickjs.h... yes
checking for JS_NewRuntime() in -lquickjs... no
missing JS_NewRuntime
```

I'm unsure how to processed. Without the `find_library` calls the Makefile generates, however it fails when compiling with:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _JS_NewRuntime
```

**Note**:

Here is my sample `quickrb.c` file:

```
#include <quickjs/quickjs.h>

#include <ruby.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>

void Init_quickrb()
{
  const char *filename = "runtime";
  const char *script = "3 + 4";
  const size_t length = strlen(script);

  JSRuntime *runtime = JS_NewRuntime();
  JSContext *context = JS_NewContext(runtime);

  JSValue value = JS_Eval(context, script, length, filename, JS_EVAL_TYPE_GLOBAL);

  const char *result = JS_ToCString(context, value);
  printf("%s = %s\n", script, result);
  JS_FreeCString(context, result);

  JS_FreeContext(context);
  JS_FreeRuntime(runtime);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is:

```
find_library('quickjs', 'JS_NewRuntime', '/usr/local/lib/quickjs')
```

Because [the documentation](https://apidock.com/ruby/MakeMakefile/find_library) says:

> find_library(lib, func, ***paths**, &b) public
>
> Returns whether or not the entry point func can be found within the library lib **in one of the paths specified**, where paths is an array of strings. If func is nil , then the main() function is used as the entry point.
>
> If lib is found, then the path it was found on is added to the list of library paths searched and linked against.